# How to change session values in php

Tags: php

i am trying to change the value of a session var in php.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $_SESSION["registratie_data"]["straat"] = $_POST["straat"];
    $_SESSION["registratie_data"]["nummer"] = $_POST["nummer"];
    $_SESSION["registratie_data"]["gemeente"] = $_POST["gemeente"];
    $_SESSION["registratie_data"]["postcode"] = $_POST["postcode"];
}
$registratie_data    =   $_SESSION['registratie_data'];

if(isset($_POST["edit_button"])) {
    foreach($registratie_data as $key => $value) {
        if($key == $_GET["focus"]) {
            $value = $_POST["edit_value"];
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

As you see i am trying to change the value in the foreach loop. This actually works and when i echo the value, i see the result i want... But then to display this value in html, doesnt work.

Anyone who can tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

This is my html code, if anyone needs this in order to help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        li {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="?session=destroy">Vernietig sessie</a>
    <h1>Registratiegegevens</h1>
    <?php if(isset($_POST["submit"]) || isset($_POST["edit_button"]) ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($registratie_data as $key => $value): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $value . " | "  ?> 
            <a href="?focus=<?php echo $key ?>">wijzig</a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <?php elseif(isset($_GET["focus"])): ?>


            <form action="#" method=POST>
              <ul>
               <li> 
                <?php echo $_GET["focus"] ?>
                <input type="text" name="edit_value" ?>
                <input type="submit" name="edit_button" value="Opslaan">
                </li>
              </ul>
            </form>

    <?php else: ?>
    <form action="#" method=POST>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="straat">Straat</label>
                <input type="text" name="straat">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="nummer">Nummer</label>
                <input type="text" name="nummer">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="gemeente">Gemeente</label>
                <input type="text" name="gemeente">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="postcode">postcode</label>
                <input type="text" name="postcode">
            </li>
            <input class="el" type="submit" name="submit" value="Volgende">
        </ul>
    </form>
    <?php endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"when i echo the value, i see the result i want"* - You're seeing the value you just set on the previous line.  But you're not actually modifying anything in `$registratie_data`.

Comment: Make sure you're using `session_start();` at top of your page and don't forget to include `$registratie_data` before foreach when output HTML.

Comment: Ah yes, i see that now

Answer (score 0):

1.In PHP file your assigning the session value to $registratie_data variable the your using foreach loop to print.
   here $registratie_data as session data

2. In HTML file your not assigning any data to $registratie_data variable so it have empty data.
   here $registratie_data empty data

   so you need to assign data to $registratie_data as shown below to get required

     //you need to assgin the session value

   ```
   <?php foreach($registratie_data as $key => $value): ?>
       <li>
           <?php echo $value . " | "  ?> 
           <a href="?focus=<?php echo $key ?>">wijzig</a>
       </li>
   <?php endforeach ?>
   ```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You dont change the value of registration_data in the foreach loop. I think it should look like this:

```
foreach($registratie_data as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $_GET["focus"]) {
        $registratie_data[$key] = $_POST["edit_value"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot this line of code from the first example in your HTML example:

```
$registratie_data    =   $_SESSION['registratie_data'];
```